# right alignment footnotetext

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes

I want to change my foot from left position to right positions in twocolumn article without numbering , so i rewrite part of code but my foot note is always is left how can change the position of line and text to bottom of page in the right column like image below.

Mycode

```
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via 
 $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe  }

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%

  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blfootnote{author information}



\begin{abstract}
abstract.....
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
 ....
 ....
     ....

\end{document}
```

I want a footnote like this image
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Please add  compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and not an image of your code.

Comment: i post my code please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\afterpage` to force `\footnotetext` into the next column.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via 
 $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe  }

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{#1}%
  %\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}% not needed
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\afterpage{\blfootnote{author information}}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-5]\footnote{Number test.}
\end{document}
```